# How to read a jar file inside a zip file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have a large zip file that contains many jar files. I want to read the content of the jar files.

What I tried is to read the inner jar file into memory, which seem to work (see below). However, I am not sure how large the jar files can be, and am concerned that they won't fit into memory.

Is there streaming solution for this problem?

```
hello.zip
+- hello.jar
   +- Hello.class

#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os
import io
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('hello.zip', 'r')
for zipname in zip.namelist():
    if zipname.endswith('.jar'):
        print(zipname)
        jarname = zip.read(zipname)
        memfile = io.BytesIO(jarname)
        jar = zipfile.ZipFile(memfile) 
        for f in jar.namelist():
            print(f)

hello.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Hello.class
```

Comment: Can't you do `extract` or `extractall` to temporary disk if you're worried about memory? Then `close` the zipfile and repeat for the jar?

Comment: But really unless we are talking about gigabytes size zip files here, things should be fine.

Comment: Maybe with [`zlib.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress)?

Comment: @Alper: Just measured the jar files: the average is 11 MB, there are a few in the range of 100 to 300 MB. So you think I should be fine processing them in memory?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: thanks for the hint, I'll look into that.

Comment: I don't know the memory characteristics of the machine you want to do this on. On a desktop I wouldn't give this a second thought.